# how to open a simulink file created in older version to a newer version of matlab simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have taken a file of simulink  from another laptop whose matlab version was 2015a.But my computer got the matlab of version 2021a . As a result I'm unable to open the file. If anyone can give me any idea on this ,it would really be a great help for me.

I have tried looking for the solutions on youtube but there was none regarding this type of problem. it is not showing anything like that the file is corrupted or damaged or it is unable to open. It is just not opening

Comment: I don't think that should cause an issue, MATLAB will open the .slx in the newer version and if you save it you will likely be prompted that the old version has been saved as a .2015a file as a backup in case you need it, and the new version will be compatible with versions from 2021a. Please [edit] your question to show the actual verbatim error you are getting when trying to open the file

Comment: thanks a lot for your valuable response but the .slx file is not opening  on the 2021a

Comment: So per the 2nd half of my comment, please [edit] your question to show the actual error message you're getting. Does it definitely open OK in 2015a? What happens when you _try_ to open it in 21a?

Answer (score 0):

Simulink 2021a support file format form previous versions such as 2015a thus the problem might be away from a versioning issue. if you have a 2021a model try to save it with a previous version with:  Save > Export Model to > Previous Version from Simulink Toolstrip , and work with it in Simulink 2015a